# Resume CaptureElement after application was suspended in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, webcam

I'm developing a metro application that lets you interact with your webcam. There is only one problem, when the application is passed in the background the webcam is turned off. To resolve this problem, I used this code:

```
Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += Current_VisibilityChanged;

async void Current_VisibilityChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.VisibilityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Visible)
            await mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();
        else
            await mediaCaptureMgr.StopPreviewAsync();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

It works perfectly when debugging, but if the application is started normally the code is executed but the webcam is not activated again once I brought the application in the foreground. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code runs in debug mode because you app is never truly suspended. When executing normally, the app is suspended and then resumed in the course of normal process lifetime.  Changing from suspend to resume does not trigger a `VisibilityChanged` event.  If you use the Suspend/Resume button in Visual Studio while debugging, you should see your code fail like it does during normal execution.

You need to move the code into your `OnLaunched` method in *App.xaml.cs*.  Note, you will need to account for the application possibly being terminated and needed to reinitialize the entire media capturer object.